constructing a template class with a reference does not compile
I am building a template class that must be able to hold a value or a reference.
I am building the library for C++11 compatibility.
Here is the relevant code for the class
template<typename T>
    class Foo
    {
      private:
        T _Data;

      public:
        Foo(const T& i_Data) :
          _Data(i_Data)
        {}

        virtual ~Foo()
        {}

        Foo(const Foo &i_Other):
          _Data(i_Other._Data)
        {};

        Foo(Foo &&io_Other):
        _Data(std::move(io_Other._Data))
        {}
        // etc..
     };


The code works excepted when creating a Foo object in this way:
double Bar = 2.5;
Foo<double&> f = Bar; // This does not compile (in c++11, C++20 works though)
                      // error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘double&’ to an rvalue of type ‘std::remove_reference<double&>::type’ {aka ‘double’}
Foo<double&> f(Bar);  // This does compile

I figured that when using the first line, the compiler tries to build a temporary Foo, and then move this into the Foo, although i don't understand why and how to cleanly avoid this (Of course, i could remove the move constructor but that's a cheesy fix)
Also, why does it work with C++17 and not C++11. From what i can see this is not a problem related to template deduction so this should work the same in both standards right?

With Foo<double&> you say that the template type T is the type double&. Which means that the constructor is taking a reference to a reference to a double as argument (double& &) which really makes no sense.

Think of a reference as an alternative way to write "pointer to" and think, what happens, when your variable goes out of scope.

cannot reproduce https://godbolt.org/z/c5oxMWxbc, and its a little fishy that the error mentions std::remove_reference which isnt present in the code

@KungPhoo nothing is going out of scope in the example.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai You didnt specifiy that the standard was c++11. When you do this it does not compile and the std::remove_reference appears as it is called inside the std::move function.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai the error exists in C++11 and 14, not clear why and though OP design is debatable ;), its question about what change between 14 and 17 that makes the code working is interesting

@Oersted ok, someone messed with my godbolt ;). I changed the C++20 in the quesiton to C++17, because it was misleading. I expected to see the error until before C++20 (ie also with 17)

@Oersted Yeah that was the question. Moreover, i of course removed a lot of stuff from the class but if you have advices on what could be done better i'm open to suggestions. I did it this way because from what i recall from the standard, when you write  T& Type and the later explicitly tell the compiler that T is a reference type, such as double&, in C++11 the compiler will consider the double& & as a basic reference type double&. If i'm wrong, can you point me to the relevant cppreference page?

@KungPhoo of course eventually things do go out of scope, but as Bar and Foo are on the stack, defined in that order, Foo will be destroyed first, then Bar. This is the one case of a reference member that is ok, imho, as a short lived wrapper (in the complete code I'd expect copying and moving to be deleted, but thats out of scope of the question)

You can see Jan Schultke answer. For reference collapsing: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference. You can also complete with the different kinds of initializations in C++ (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization). They have different behaviors with respect to construction from a different type. And thus the answer is indeed "copy elision", I think (I overlooked it while I recently posted a question on the subject...).

In Foo<double&>, the constructor taking const T& would have a type you probably didn't expect as the result of reference collapsing. See also What are the reference collapsing rules, and how are they utilized by the C++ standard library?
You are forming a "const lvalue reference to lvalue reference to double" which collapses into "reference to double", so your constructor is effectively:
Foo(double& i_Data)

Thus,
Foo<double&> f = Bar;

... is perfectly fine, since Bar is an lvalue.
Prior to C++17, there was no mandatory copy elision in this case, and the above line would implicitly convert Bar to Foo<double&> and then use the move constructor, but your move constructor doesn't handle T = double& properly.
You attempt to bind the _Data member (of type double&) to a double&& returned by std::move, and that's not allowed.
The compiler was allowed to elide this copy and the call to the move constructor, but at least on paper, the call has to be valid.
Since C++17, copy-initialization simply calls Foo(const T&) directly and does not create any temporary objects, so the move constructor is irrelevant.
However, you would run into trouble if you actually tried to use the move constructor just as in C++11.
Personal recommendation
Disallow the use of references for Foo. Things get really weird when reference collapsing gets involved, and it's most likely more trouble than it's worth to support the case where T is a reference.
Also note that _Data is a reserved name. See also What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?

Ok thanks for the explanation. As for the recommendation, i'm quite stuck as i really need this to work with references (in fact it's the only reason i need this). For context, i need to have all of my variables stored in a contiguous char array somewhere in memory and delegate the construction to a "Manager" which would then return a reference to the built data, which would then be stored in an object. How would you suggest that i do this differently? (it must be generic)

That's not enough details to make any concrete suggestion, and the comment section here isn't the best place to discuss it. The best place is https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ You should make post there and provide all relevant details in a new post.

Hum, I'm not quite understand what you're saying about the collapsing within the constructor. Foo(const T& i_Data) is equivalent to Foo(T const & i_Data), which, IMHO, is clearer. Then T is double&giving Foo(double& const & i_Data) and references are immutable thus we can remove the const: Foo(double&& i_Data). Why would there be reference collapsing in this case?

@Oersted lvalue references to lvalue references don't turn into rvalue references. The result isn't &&. There is reference collapsing because there is no such thing as a reference to a reference in the type system, so the standard says what this type turns into instead.

Thx my bad: its not copy and pasting (which would give a rvalue ref) but taking a reference on a reference (just as you said) that does not exist and collapse to a simple reference (first example here). Understood (till I thumble again on this one later ;-6)
